# Dual boot ubuntu 13.10 and windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my pre-installed windows 7 pc and I want a dual boot. I have no empty partition on my hard disk drive. I don't want to re-install windows 7 and don't want to install ubuntu on c drive. I want to install on a different partition but I want to resize it. How should I do it? Please answer in steps. Also suggest the amount of space I should allocte to ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 3):

1.Create a bootable cd/usb of ubuntu and boot it.
2.Choose try ubuntu option
3.When the ubuntu opens search in the dash for gparted
[image]

4.Use gparted to resize your disk
5.Right click on the drive in which windows is installed
6.Unmount it
7.Right click again and choose resize/move
[image]

8.resize the disk and create a new partition after resizing
9.After rezing windows partition use boot repair
Follow these commands for bootreapir

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After installing boot repair select recommended settings for boot repair
[image]

Comment: By default gparted was not present in live disk,plz add up the commands to install gparted.

Comment: To install Gparted in Ubuntu Linux enter the following in the terminal.sudo apt-get install gparted Press ENTER and type sudo gparted for launching it from terminal

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly the same with my Ultrabook (Windows 8 preinstalled) 250 GB SSD.
This was the only option because I didn't even get an installmedia for W8.

For every step I booted with the appropriate live CD/DVD

1.) Backup whole Disk on an external USB drive with clonezilla
http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php

2.) Shrinked the largest windows partition with gparted to about 100GB.
http://gparted.org/download.php

3.) Installed Ubuntu in the newly created free space
(New Partition for / and SWAP in this free space, used whole Partition for / (no home and var partitions etc))

4.) Repaired GRUB for dualboot with boot-repair (default settings, worked really great!)
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/

On reboot I got everything in the boot menu! WOW!

Kind regards

Justus Gadient

Answer (score 0):

Right click on my computer>manage. then go to storage>disk management. Right click on you current partition>shrink. this will allow you to make the current partition smaller and will create free space for new partition for ubuntu installation. 20-40 GB should be plenty for simple use.