# dual booting windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04, hard disk partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, window

I have a sony vaio vpcf121fx laptop with windows 8.1 currently installed in it..i have never dual booted ubuntu in my laptop before..i have a 1 TB hard disk and its divided into C:,D:,E: and F: partitions with C: storing the current windows 8.1 OS....i want to allocate about 25 GB of storage space for ubuntu...and want to allocate  that 25 GB memory from  E: drive which currently has 300 GB free out of 345 GB...how do i go about doing it...
i have a vague idea about shrinking the drive or something..but i dont know anything about it...could someone please explain the exact steps that i must follow in order to ensure that i successfully install ubuntu 14.04 without losing the data stored in the hard disk currently?

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://askubuntu.com/questions/378320/dual-boot-ubuntu-13-10-and-windows-7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378320/dual-boot-ubuntu-13-10-and-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 go to search(right side of the screen) and type "Disk Management".
 Select "Create and format hard disk partitions".
 Right click on E: and choose "Shrink Volume".
 Enter the values and you will get new unallocated space near E:.